# Where is OpenQasmReader in Q#?

Tags: q#, qasm

OpenQasmReader was added in https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/pull/58. I can't find this code on the latest clone of the aforementioned repository. Going through the commits, I found that it had been de-referenced in the [README](https://github.com/microsoft/Quantum/pull/235/files).

Answer (score 1):

OpenQasmReader was moved to [another repository](https://github.com/qsharp-community/qsharp-integrations).